How do I see my comments on someone else's Facebook profile posts, using desktop?
How do I see my comments on someone else's Facebook profile posts, using desktop?
I've tried going to Comments in my Activity Log, but there's filter option or other way to specify which person's profile I want to see my comments on.
I've tried going to the person's profile, and I don't see any way to search for my comments there.
Thanks
